# Sans serif old-style numerals?

Tags: oldstylenums

is it possible to get old-style numerals as sans serif? \oldstylenums is with serifs only as far as I see.
Or do I need an additional font? (if yes, which one would be suggested?)

Cheers and thanks,
  Thomas

Comment: There is an example, Classic Grotesque, at http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures.  Futura and Gill Sans also seem to posses them, as well as Nexus: http://www.martinmajoor.com/6_my_philosophy.html

Comment: Also, FF Scala Sans: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FF_Scala_Sans

Comment: Did you mean [lowercase numbers](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/54423)? ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to stick with the default TeX font, then you could use `cfr-lm`.  This font isn't exactly Computer Modern, but Latin Modern, a modern clone of CM.  The package allows to customize the font loading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sf=oldstyle]{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
\textsf{1234567890}
\end{document}
```

or you could switch to old style numerals on demand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
\textsf{\oldstylenums{1234567890}}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

In XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX it is much simpler.  `fontspec` changes the default font to Latin Modern anyways, so it is just a matter of adjusting the features for the Sans font  (switching on demand with `\oldstylenums` works as well).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Latin Modern Sans}
\begin{document}
\textsf{1234567890}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: For `cfr-lm`: Note that I think `\ostyle` and `\texto{}` may be preferable to `\oldstylenums` because they do not require an encoding switch. Also `sf=oldstyle` does nothing because you'd get proportional oldstyle figures by default anyway.

Comment: This means, in particular, you can easily mix text with a different style of numbers. For example, `\textpl{AB12 3DC}` for a UK postcode or US zip, if oldstyle figures are default for the document. (I use this a lot.) Because the fonts are there, there is no need to resort to the supplementary encoding to access these figures. You can just switch families temporarily, which I think is much more satisfactory. At least, I could be mistaken. But that's why I did it that way. Of course, I'm biased ;).

Comment: That looks quite good! Many Thanks! So far I have skipped {Xe,Lua}LaTex but probably I should give them also a try

Answer (score 10):

There are quite a few Opentype sans-serif font families out there that feature old-style numerals as an option. However, since they are Opentype fonts, you will need to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to access them.

Not knowing anything about your document, I don't think it's helpful to recommend any particular sans-serif font. The following code shows ten different sans-serif fonts I found on my system that feature old-style numerals.

[image]

```
%% Compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,array}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
\newcommand{\doline}[1]{\setsansfont{#1}\sffamily#1\quad0123456789\par}
\begin{document}
\doline{Calibri}  
\doline{Calibri Light}
\doline{Latin Modern Sans}
\doline{Linux Biolinum O}
\doline{Myriad Pro} 
\doline{Optima nova LT Pro}
\doline{Palatino Sans Com}
\doline{Skia Regular}
\doline{TeX Gyre Heros}
\doline{Biome Std Semi Bold}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

I recommend looking at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html for more possibilities.

For the following fonts, **no `fontspec` is required**, which means they compile in pdflatex.

---

Here is Alegreya Sans.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{AlegreyaSans} %% Option 'black' gives heavier bold face
%% The 'sfdefault' option to make the base font sans serif
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\AlegreyaSansOsF #1}}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Carlito:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
%% The 'lf' option for lining figures
%% The 'sfdefault' option to make the base font sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Fira Sans:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

GFS Neohellenic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} %% LGR encoding is needed for loading the package gfsneohellenic
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Iwona:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Iwona Condensed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Iwona Light:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Iwona Light Condensed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[light,condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

KP Sans Serif:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts} %% sfmath option only to make math in sans serif. Probablye only for use when base font is sans serif.
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Kurier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that Kurier also offers versions in condensed, light, and light condensed (not shown here).

---

Mintspirit (only comes in OSF):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{mintspirit}
\begin{document}
0123456789 %vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Source Sans Pro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123456789 vs \oldstylenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]